# Addon domains redirect to main domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a hosting service with two addon domains.

All was working well till few weeks ago.

If I enter www.addon1.com, it redirects to www.mainwebsite.com. Same happens for www.addon2.com.

But if I enter www.addon1.com/index.php, it loads properly.

I really do not know what the problem is.

Is there anything I can do ( htaccess or something else ) to ensure that www.addon1.com does not redirect to www.mainwebsite.com

**EDIT**

Content of www.addon1.com .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes
```

Content of www.mainwebsite.com .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes
Redirect 301 /index.html http://www.mainwebsite.com/index.php
Redirect 301 /portfolio.html http://www.mainwebsite.com/portfolio/index.php
Redirect 301 /services.html http://www.mainwebsite.com/services/index.php
```

Comment: Did you look into your `.htaccess` file? If you don't understand please post the contents of it.

Comment: Yes, I did. Please find the htaccess content in my edit

Comment: It doesn't seem that you are problem relies on `.htaccess` can you confirm you did not set the redirection from your cpanel?

Comment: @RahilWazir There is no cpanel redirect.

Comment: it's not clear what exactly you want to do, and what's an addon domain? a domain that doesn't have its own docroot?

Comment: @dalu, yes, an addon domain is added as a folder under the /www and accessed as an independent domain.

Comment: do you have access to the configurations of each vhost? (/etc/apache2/vhosts or similar) and what do your DNS records looks like? Do I understand correctly that you don't want any redirection happening at all no matter if / or /file.php is called?

Comment: So how are your domains set up in httpd.conf? Does `apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS` give you any hints?

Comment: @dalu, yes, I do not want any redirection. I do not have access to /etc/apache2/vhosts

Comment: @miken32, I do not have root access on server.

Comment: then you should ask your webhost for support

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a **'bypass rule'** at the top to skip the subsequent rules if the request is for the addon (in our case the www.addon1.com).

Add to `www.mainwebsite.com` 's `.htaccess` file at the top the following:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?addon1\.com
    RewriteRule .* - [L]
...
```

*info for [L] rule [here](http://dev.filkor.org/2014/01/09/dot-htaccess-examples-and-explanations/).

- **EXPLANATION**

This tells [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to quit processing right here if the requested domain is addon1.com or www.addon1.com.

To help you more i tried the senario at this excellent online rule test tool: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/
and i give you the results.

**1st Type**: www.addon1.com

**Result**: Stop processing and other rules below could not met!
[image]

**2nd Type**: www.whatever.com

**Result**: Continue processing and could met other rules!
[image]

Finally, you can add whatever rule you want bellow this piece of code and it will work!
Be carefull,we made changes only to the domain `.htaccess` file

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your .htaccess for the addon site is missing the 301 redirect:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /(.*)   http://www.mainsite.de/index.php
```

You may want to use multiple statements with different patters if you don't want to redirect all requests to the same destination on the main site.